# Video en HTML tapa H3 en version movil

Tags: html, css, sass, video, headers

Estoy realizando el proyecto de un curso en el que se coloca por medio de HTML5 un video en forma de portada, y por encima un h3 y párrafo en forma de título, de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="video">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="contenedor contenido-video">
            <h2>Rock & EDM Festival</h2>
            <p>Julio 2022, Guadalajara, México</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="video/concierto.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video/concierto.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="video/concierto.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>
```

El problema surge que al revisar el resultado de la sección del video en distintas resoluciones, en la PC, todo se ve normal, pero luego de hacer el deployment y abrir la web en mi celular, el video tapa el h3 y el párrafo que debería ir por encima. Adjunto imagenes:

Revisando la web en pc en resolución de celular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Web vista desde el celular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El SASS aplicado a la sección de video (No puedo adjuntar el código directamente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El CSS fue hecho con SASS, minificado con cssnano y utilicé autoprefixer, aún no intenté quitandolos.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente a `overlay` ponle un `z-index` por lo menos de 1.

```
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
```

*El `contenido-video` no necesita `z-index` porque no es de posición absoluta ni necesita sobreponerse a nada*.

Prueba y luego a ver qué tal.